# What driver does Linux use for generic UEFI video

Tags: linux, video, uefi, display-driver, vesa

Let's say I don't have the vendor specific GPU driver on the Linux distro. What is the generic driver that's used when booted in UEFI mode? I know it's not VESA. I checked the DRM github page and can't see any generic drivers. Maybe it doesn't even use DRM?

I'm only asking because I never had luck booting up to GUI (got only console) when a  video driver was missing. In theory I should get "generic" video like in BIOS mode, right?

Answer (score 2):

UEFI provides GOP (Graphics Output Protocol) as the basic video output. To use this on Linux as efifb, you must enable `CONFIG_FB_EFI` during kernel compilation.

The efifb driver does not use DRM – it only provides a basic framebuffer device `/dev/fb0` (similarly to vesafb). You'll need some special configuration to make Xorg pick that up (i.e. install the `xf86-video-fbdev` Xorg module), and chances are that newer display servers (Wayland compositors) won't support non-DRM framebuffers at all.

Comment: So what you are saying is that there are no UEFI “generic video” drivers for DRM, only FB? Because vesa does have DRM drivers?